# Creating organisation with 2 peers

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to extend [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/education/tree/master/LFS171x/fabric-material) code to add 1 more endorsing peer in the organization org1. I updated `/basic-network/crypto-config.yaml` as follows:

```
PeerOrgs:
- Name: Org1
Domain: org1.example.com
Template:
  Count: 2
Users:
  Count: 1
```

Then I regenerated all the crypto material by running `generate.sh` again. I updated the FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE in the `basic-network/docker-compose.yaml` file. I added peer1.org1.example.com in docker-compose.yaml:

```
peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7056
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7056:7056
      - 7058:7058
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb
      - peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - basic
```

I ran the following commands then:

```
set -ev
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com peer1.org1.example.com couchdb
```

All the containers are up and running without any error.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
3393fc796417        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tuna-app-1.0-b58eb592ed6ced10f52cc063bda0c303a4272089a3f9a99000d921f94b9bae9b   "chaincode -peer.add…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                                         dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tuna-app-1.0
a45d7e943068        hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                   "/bin/bash"              2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                                         cli
d3698fc6d3d3        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                    "peer node start"        2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7056->7056/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7058->7058/tcp   peer1.org1.example.com
b7c92a70fc89        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                    "peer node start"        2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
21fabe33e3e5        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                      "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.example.com
ddaf8390c0ee        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                 "tini -- /docker-ent…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
38bdb92c6de0        hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                 "orderer"                2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
```

Next, I need to create channel with two peers. How do I modify the below commands to add peer1 to org1?

```
# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

Above two commands run successfully, but when I try to run following

`docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block`

I get following error:

`Error: Error getting endorser client channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer1.org1.example.com:7056: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded`

Answer (score 1):

Keep using `7051` and `7053` as **internal ports** for your peers, only the **exposed ports** must be changed :

```
ports:
      - 7056:7051
      - 7058:7053
```

I can't find any official documentation on this but it seems that by default it always use the address of the **anchor peer** of the organization. Ports used for handling incoming request for peers in an organization should be **the same** as the anchor peer port of that organization.

From the [core.yaml config file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/sampleconfig/core.yaml).

> # The Address at local network interface this Peer will listen on.
> # By default, it will listen on all network interfaces
> **listenAddress: 0.0.0.0:7051**
>
> [...]
>
> # When used as peer config, this represents the endpoint to other peers
> # in the same organization. For peers in other organization, see
> # gossip.externalEndpoint for more info.
> # When used as CLI config, this means the peer's endpoint to interact with
> address: 0.0.0.0:7051
>
> [...]
>
> gossip:
>       # Bootstrap set to initialize gossip with.
>       # This is a list of other peers that this peer reaches out to at startup.
>       # Important: The endpoints here have to be endpoints of peers in the same
>       # organization, because the peer would refuse connecting to these endpoints
>       # unless they are in the same organization as the peer.
>       bootstrap: 127.0.0.1:7051

If you really want to use another internal port (like `7056`), try defining `CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS` in your *docker-compose* file for your new peer (defines the GRPC server's listen port) :

```
CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7056
```

Also I suggest you not to use the same **CouchDb** as ledger database for all your peers. Use a couchDB per peer (and it is recommended to set a username/password).

**EDIT** : As you don't run the `peer channel join` commands from your `cli` container, I think you have to [fetch](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/peer-commands.html#the-peer-channel-fetch-command) the channel through the orderer on your new peer to be able to join it (this will return the most recent configuration block for the targeted channel) :

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel fetch config -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel
```

Then you should be able to join your peer to the channel using the new created block (`<channelID>_config.block`).

Comment: I did change the internal ports as you said, and then after create channel, Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel, i ran this command:
`docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block`
The same error persists.. Is the order in which i am making function calls is correcy?

Comment: The order is correct, and the one of which you join the peers doesn't matter.
But as you don't run the `peer channel join` from your `cli` container, I think you have to fetch the channel through the orderer on your new peer to be able to join it to the channel. I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: I ran the command you added, it gives the following command:
`2018-09-09 15:05:36.249 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-09-09 15:05:36.253 UTC [main] main -> INFO 002 Exiting.....`
After that I again try `peer channel join` and I get following error:
`Error: Error getting endorser client channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer1.org1.example.com:7056: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded`

Comment: I tried this command:
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e `"CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block`
and it worked. Thanks for your help. Can you please also tell me how can I be sure that peer1 is the part of channel, endorsement process, chaincode is installed and its ledger is getting updated for all transaction?

Comment: Indeed you can join channel from `peer0` container using address of `peer1`, but it should have worked using `fetch` before joining from `peer1` container. I personnaly do all the joins from the `cli` container. To make sure a peer as joined a channel use `peer channel list` which lists the channels for that peer. There are no way to list all peers that have joined a channel (I know this was planned so maybe it is possible in latest releases). The best way to make sure that the setup is correct is to make transactions and observe the responses/logs. Also take a look at Hyperledger Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do check Hyperledger Explorer. `peer channel list` on peer0 displays mychannel, but on peer1 it gives error:
Error: Error getting endorser client channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer1.org1.example.com:7056: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded. I guess peer1 is not added on the channel then.

Comment: It tries to connect on `7056`, did you changed the port everywhere in the configuration ?